# I've been editing a json file but the file itself isn't updating (python)

Tags: python, json, database

I'm trying to edit a dictionary I put in a json database and have simplified the code down to just the simple code but it isn't working:
(python)

```
with open ("./userdata/" + str(int(author.id)) + ".json", "r") as f:
                fileLoaded = json.load(f)
            fileLoaded["dollars"] -= cost
```

But the file isn't being modified. I know for a fact I'm accessing the correct file because it's not throwing up any errors and I can read fileLoaded. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks friends

Comment: You need to write back your JSON with the modified data. You're only editing in memory.

Comment: You're opening the file for `"r"`, so *reading*. Once you've modified the data, you'll want to open a file for writing to write the result. You can also open the file for both, read it, change it, seek to the beginning of the file and write the contents, but there's no reason for the extra complication, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file, and then dump the file after you have edited it in order for it to save. Try adding this to the bottom of the code:

```
with open ("./userdata/" + str(int(author.id)) + ".json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(fileLoaded, f)
```

Comment: You just have to be sure the file have been closed before writing back

Comment: You're right I wasn't opening it for writing and dumping. Thanks my guy +1

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing it to the file. `json.load` doesn't give a "magical reference" which can be used to edit the file. After modifying the dictionary, save it with `json.dump`. Like this:

```py
f.close()
with open("./userdata/" + str(int(author.id)) + ".json", 'w' as f):
    json.dump(fileLoaded, f)
```